# SQL command or trigger needed to capture changes in tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, audit

I want a query or trigger that will identify what changes done in the database tables from the Third Party Software such CMS etc.
I want to check that which data is modifying with time.
There is no log maintained in that Third Party Software so i want to check it thorugh SQL Server

Comment: Your choices are: Change tracking, change data capture, audit, roll-your-own triggers.

Comment: Yes i want to track each change

Comment: You need to research those features and determine which is best for your use case. We can't tell you that, but if you pick one and have problems implementing, we can help at that point.

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of examples you can search .. one approach of a trigger that logs deletes/updates in a table.

You must first create a `LOG` table with the the same schema of the source table and add 3 columns - `type(char1), dateLog datetime, UserLog(varchar(50)`

```
CREATE TRIGGER logTable
ON [dbo].[table] 
AFTER DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_table (<column list here>)
     SELECT del.*
        , CASE WHEN 
            EXISTS (
                select * 
                from inserted
                ) 
            AND EXISTS (
                select * 
                from deleted
                ) THEN 'U' ELSE 'D' END
        , getdate()
        , SYSTEM_USER
    FROM deleted del;
END

GO
```